# Cannot install pcscd on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, I did

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y pcscd
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pcscd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

It's strange because it shows here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/pcscd

Comment: Is universe enabled in your package sources?

Comment: @nobody no. Does it come enabled by default?